# Python multiprocessing: Better print statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, parallel-processing, stdout

Let's say we have a three processes that we want to run in parallel using Python's `multiprocessing` library.

All three processes are running foo:

```
def foo(id):
    target = 100 * 1000
    for i in range(1, target):
        progress = round(i / target * 100, 2)
        print(f'foo{id} progress:{progress}%')
```

This is the code that runs the three processes in parallel

```
import multiprocessing
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=3)
    pool.map(foo, [1,2,3])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Running this code produces an unhelpful, garbled mess in your console:
[image: A garbled mess of console output]

How can we write our print statements to neatly output the following:

```
foo1 progress: 44.44%
foo2 progress: 44.43%
foo3 progress: 44.42%
```

Such that...

1. There's no more than three lines on the console at all times
2. The percentages are updated in place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The key is to return to the same position after each print

After writing the first line, you can use the `ESC` `[` `F` code to go up one line. Repeat that string several times to go up more than one line.

Each time you are returning to the start of the first line.

```
UP_ONE_LINE="\033[F"

# When writing a message for the top line:
print("progress ..."+UP_ONE_LINE)

# When writing a message for the second line:
print("\n"*1+"progress ..."+UP_ONE_LINE*2)

# When writing a message for the second line:
print("\n"*2+"progress ..."+UP_ONE_LINE*3)
```

#### In my experience it is important to pre-assemble the string

If you just use this pattern:

```
print("")
print("")
print("progress",UP_ONE_LINE,UP_ONE_LINE,UP_ONE_LINE)
```

... the different `print`s may become interleaved, rather than all the prints of one process happening in rapid succession.

Indeed, even the various comma-separated items in a single print might be interleaved between the processes.

So it is best for each process to assemble a *single* string, and then send it for `print`ing.